# Sequelize query in query

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have 2 models Shop and Beacon. I have to return sum beacons assigned to each shop. I know how to do it in SQL:

```
SELECT Shops.*, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Beacons WHERE shopId = Shops.id) FROM Shops
```

But i have a problem with Sequelize, i try something like below:

```
models.Shop.findAll({
  attributes: ['id', sqz.fn('count', sqz.col('shopId'))],
  include: [
    {
      model: models.Beacon
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: what error do you get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution work, but return query:

```
SELECT Shop.*, count(shopId) FROM Shops LEFT OUTER JOIN Beacons ON Shop.id = Beacons.shopId
```